# Can you make a 3d game in eclipse java?

Tags: java, 3d, software-engineering

Hello can you make a 3d game like minecraft using java?

Comment: This must be the most random question I've encountered here yet. You're asking if you can make 3D games in Eclipse, mention that you know it's not a Unity question and you give it the tag "minecraft". This is just pure gold :D

Comment: I just want to know lol sorry man i used that unity thing

Comment: Eclipse is just an IDE. It doesn't limit the kind of programs you can make.

Comment: I give this question a "Star" (but not an _upvote_) only because I am so entertained by how "_specifically general_" it is.  @heishe:  Random?  Well, it certainly wasn't predictable.  ;-D

Comment: Voted to close, not constructive.

Comment: Voted to close as well. Same reason.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  You can create a 3D game like Minecraft in Java using Eclipse as your source code editor, but that's not all you'll need...

An MMORPG will require a lot of work (MMORPGs aren't known to be small projects), so you'll need a variety of tools for other aspects of the project:

- graphics editors for various graphics (e.g., logo for the game)
- 3D modeling tools (to create/modify 3D graphics)
- word processor for the planning documents (a detailed plan is highly recommended)
- word processor for writing story-lines (assuming there is at least one story-line)
- word processor for documentation (your users will want some documentation)
- web site development/maintenance tools (assuming there will be a web site)
- accounting software (if your users need to pay for anything)
- database management tools (you need to save user data and game state at the very least)

(If I've missed some important tools:  Please make mention of each tool {and its use}, each in a separate comment {if nobody else has}, and I will likely *upvote* it.)

Comment: Minecraft in fact is written in Java.

Comment: @Tim Holt:  +1 because you just made me laugh at myself.  =D